# Discord.js v12 - How to add a role?

Tags: javascript, discord.js, roles

```
if (message.content == '/lv') {
    message.member.roles.add('705757268448378971');
    message.react('✅') 
}
if (message.content == '/lv remove') {
    message.member.roles.remove('705757268448378971');
    message.react('✅')
}
//TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined
```

Code should add role to member after '/lv' command and remove the same role after '/lv remove'. Previously worked perfectly with addRole.

Comment: Have you tried to log `message.member`? What does it contain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to store the role in a variable.

```js
let role = message.guild.roles.cache.get("705757268448378971");
```

Then you can try to add the role to the member:

```js
if (message.content == '/lv') {
    message.member.roles.add(role);
    message.react('✅') 
}
if (message.content == '/lv remove') {
    message.member.roles.remove(role);
    message.react('✅')
}
```

If `message.member.roles.add` still doesn't work try:

```js
message.guild.member(message.member).roles.add(role);
```

Answer (score 0):

After some digging and 3 hours of torture, I've realized that I didn't change the Discord.js version. Sorry, I'm new to Discord.js. Thank you for your answer anyways.