# auto add role discord.js v12

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I have made this welcome message for my discord bot:

```
 

client.on("guildMemberAdd", async member => {
  console.log(`Member join username: %s`, member.user.username);
  if(member.guild.id !== "951189437168091166") return; 
  
  const welcomeCard = new canvacord.Welcomer()
  
  welcomeCard.setUsername(member.user.username)
  welcomeCard.setDiscriminator(member.user.discriminator)
  
  welcomeCard.setAvatar(member.user.displayAvatarURL({format: "png"}))
  welcomeCard.setColor("title", "welcomeCard")
  welcomeCard.setColor("username-box", "welcomeCard")
  welcomeCard.setColor("discriminator-box", "welcomeCard")
  welcomeCard.setColor("message-box", "welcomeCard")
  welcomeCard.setColor("border", "welcomeCard")
  welcomeCard.setColor("avatar", "welcomeCard")
  welcomeCard.setBackground("https://img.freepik.com/vrije-vector/donker-papierlagenbehang-met-gouden-details_23-2148403401.jpg?w=360")
  welcomeCard.setMemberCount(member.guild.memberCount)
  let attachment = new Discord.MessageAttachment(await welcomeCard.build(), "welcome.png")
   member.guild.channels.cache.get("961943485315944508").send( member.toString(), attachment)
})
```

But i want the bot to add a role to the joined member when the member joins the server. I have tried multiple things, but i dont know if i can put it in this code. Can someone please help me?

Discord js (v12)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Discord.js v12 - How to add a role?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65560921/discord-js-v12-how-to-add-a-role)

Answer (score 0):

```js
let role = member.guild.roles.cache.find(r=> r.name === "your-role-name") 
member.roles.add(role)
```

Comment: do i need to add an id anywhere?

Comment: no u needn't, as u can see u get the role by its name